# Deltaspike repository transaction commits but nothing persists in DB in Java SE

Tags: java, jpa-2.1, deltaspike, deltaspike-jpa

I'm using DeltaSpike repositories to persist an entity in Java SE and I'm using file based H2 database. The problem is that while there is no error in the console, nothing gets persisted in the database. I checked the database contents using an standalone client. I also tried to fetch the contents using the repository right after the persistence is done, but got no result.

When I try to persist it directly using entity manager (pure JPA) it gets persisted and I can see the record when I open the file in a GUI client.

The project structure is like:

[image]

Here are the dependencies in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.197</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-core-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-jpa-module-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-jpa-module-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-core-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-data-module-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-data-module-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.cdictrl</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-cdictrl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.cdictrl</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-cdictrl-weld</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The `persistence.xml` file is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="sample-unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.one.ehsan.test.deltaspike.domain.Person</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:file:./data/test-h2-db"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
            <!-- Hibernate properties -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The producer class for entity manager:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class PersistenceProducer
{
    @Inject
    @PersistenceUnitName("sample-unit")
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Produces
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void closeEntityManager(@Disposes EntityManager entityManager)
    {
        if (entityManager.isOpen())
        {
            entityManager.close();
        }
   }
}
```

The entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Person
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String firstName;

    @Column
    private String lastName;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column
    private Date createDate;

    // ... getter/setters omitted
}
```

The repository class:

```
@Transactional
@Repository(forEntity = Person.class)
public abstract class PersonRepository extends AbstractEntityRepository<Person, Long>
{
    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

The service bean that calls the repository:

```
public class PersonService
{
    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Inject
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    public Person save(Person person) {

        // I tried removing begin/commit and nothing changed
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        Person result = personRepository.save(person);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        return result;
    }
}
```

The main class of the application:

```
public class Main
{
    private CdiContainer cdiContainer;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.run();
    }

    public void run() {

        cdiContainer = CdiContainerLoader.getCdiContainer();
        cdiContainer.boot();

        persistPerson();

        cdiContainer.shutdown();
    }


    private void persistPerson()
    {
        PersonService personService = (PersonService) getBean(PersonService.class);

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setFirstName("Foo");
        person.setLastName("Bar");
        person.setCreateDate(new Date());

        personService.save(person);

    }

    private Object getBean(Class type)
    {
        BeanManager beanManager = cdiContainer.getBeanManager();
        Set<Bean<?>> personServiceBean = beanManager.getBeans(type);
        Bean<?> bean = beanManager.resolve(personServiceBean);
        CreationalContext<?> context = beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean);
        return beanManager.getReference(bean, type, context);
    }
}
```

Does anybody know what may have been missed in (probably) DeltaSpike configuration? Or is it an expected behaviour in such a configuration?

Comment: So it works fine if you replace
Person result = personRepository.save(person);
by
Person result = entityManager.persist(person);
?

Comment: No, it works if I persist the entity using the entityManager:

`entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
 entityManager.persist(person);
 entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

 Person result = entityManager.find(Person.class, person.getId());`